# Deployment time at Visual Studio's output window

Tags: visual-studio, deployment

I am deploying webpart solution or another wsp project from Visual Studio and i need to see finishing time.

Are there any way to see the time when **deploy finished** or **any error** occured for interrupt the deployment. Setting detailed or any other options in *MSBuild project build output verbosity* doesnt help. Also, output verbosity setting doesnt show any other local time, any .NET projects.

Comment: Out of curiosity: what do you need it for?

Comment: Multi developer using same server for development. Sometimes deploys mixing. And sometimes deployment process takes too long. When you look other things, you are missing when did you deploy.

Answer (score 3):

You can add 'PreBuild' or 'Post-Deployment' command

ECHO ------ %TIME% ------

or change verbosity option to 'Normal' in Options -> Project & Run -> Build & Run

Refer this [link](https://blogs.blackmarble.co.uk/blogs/jfowler/post/2014/06/12/Show-build-time-in-Visual-Studio-Output-Window.aspx) for details and screen-shot.